# I can't understand why I'm receiving this output after a .reduce javascript method

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my code:

```
nicknames = {'RAM' : 'Black', 'ELC': 'Mamba', 'FAD' : 'Samba', 'NOP' : 'STOP'}

const nickGet = (initials) => {

 return initials.match(/.{1,3}/g).reduce((arr, trio) => {
    if (!nicknames[trio]) throw new Error('Invalid trio')
    return [...arr, nicknames[trio]]

})
}
```

I am getting the below output when I run nickGet("ELCRAM"):

```
["E", "L", "C", "Black"]
```

I know that if I want to make this work, I should set an initial value of [] to reduce. However, I'm wondering why when I don't, I get this specific out. How is ELC being divided into separate values in my array? What is the logic behind it here?

Thank you!

EDIT, trying to do it with map function:

```
var nicknames = { RAM: 'Black', ELC: 'Mamba', FAD: 'Samba', NOP: 'STOP' };

const nickGet = (initials) => {
  var nick = initials.match(/.../g).map((trio) => {
    if (!nicknames[trio]) throw new Error('Invalid trio')
    return nicknames[trio]

  }, []);

nick.length = nick.findIndex(element => element == "STOP");
return nick;
};
```

Anyway to do it so that maps just stops when it hits STOP? Not sure what to replace "nothing" with if any.

Comment: Using `map` would be much more appropriate here than `reduce`.

Comment: Hey, how would you use map here to arrive at the same?

Comment: Hey, so I edited my code again to show how I did it with map. Any better or faster way you propose? I can't stop the map loop so I had to set the result of my final array as a variable and then update its length @Bergi

Comment: Yes, I'd use `map` like that, except I'd drop the third argument :-)

Comment: I didn't know you wanted to stop the loop, you didn't do it in the `reduce` solution either (other than by `throw`ing that exception). And indeed you can't break from either, if you want a loop to put an `if (nicknames[trio] == "STOP") break;` inside then use `for … of` and `push` to an array.

Answer (score 3):

You do not supply an empty array as start value for the accumulator.

In the fist loop, the string `ELC` is spreaded into single characters, because this is the value for `arr`. As `trio`, you get `RAM` and this value is converted to `'Black'`.

```js
var nicknames = { RAM: 'Black', ELC: 'Mamba', FAD: 'Samba', NOP: 'STOP' };

const nickGet = (initials) => {
  return initials.match(/.../g).reduce((arr, trio) => {
    if (!nicknames[trio]) throw new Error('Invalid trio')
    return [...arr, nicknames[trio]];
  }, []);
};

console.log(nickGet('ELCRAM'));
console.log([...'ELC']);
```

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense now.

Comment: Don't you also get ELC as trio if you don't supply empty array? Or it skips now the first value since we included it in the initial?

Comment: if no start value is supplied, the accumulator is the first element of the array. the first value `'ELC'` is treated as iterable and the result of it is a spreaded string.